# How to lock row if copied cell equals to specific value?

Tags: google-apps-script

My script is locking if "I" column's cell equals to "lock", but if I copy "lock" named cell to down it will not work! I need this function for some st***d users which can't select each time "lock" value from dropdown menu.

[image]

[image]
***Don't mention cell value, I've just put my option.* Copied cell doesn't work**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  let range = e.range; //get the range of edited cell
  let value = e.value; //get the new value of edited cell
  let row = range.getRow(); //get the row
  let col = range.getColumn(); //get the column
  let last_row = range.getLastRow();
  let sheet = range.getSheet(); //get the sheet where edit is made
  let userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  let lock_range = `B${row}:${last_row}`; //set lock range using row
  let lock_description = row + " - protected"; //description text


  if(col == 9 && row >= 4 && value == "lock"){    //check the edited cell
    
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); //get all protection with type range
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++) { //loop 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == lock_description) { //row matching
        protectedRange[i].remove(); //remove protection
      }
    }

    let protection = sheet.getRange(lock_range).protect() //set protection
      .setDescription(lock_description)  //add description
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors()); //remove editors
    protection.addEditor(userEmail);
    if (protection.canDomainEdit())
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }

  else if(col == 9 && row >= 4 && value == null || value == "✅good" || value == "❌not good"){ //check if the edited cell is empty
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); //get all protection with type range
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++) { //loop 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == lock_description) { //row matching
        protectedRange[i].remove(); //remove protection
      }
    }  
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

**HELP me with this situation.**

Comment: Instead of a edit trigger, you need a button or a timed trigger, which will check every cell needed and lock accordingly. Edit trigger isn't reliable with multiple cells.

Answer (score 1):

**SUGGESTION:**

I have modified your code like this:

```
function onEdit() {

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(); // get the range
  var value = range.getValue(); //dropdown value

  let row = range.getRow(); //get the row
  let col = range.getColumn(); //get the column
  let last_row = range.getLastRow();
  let userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  let lock_range = `B${row}:${last_row}`; //set lock range using row
  let lock_description = row + " - protected"; //description text

    if ((col == 9 && row >= 4) && (value == " lock")) {//check the edited cell
      var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); //get all protection with type range
      for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++) { //loop 
        if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == lock_description) { //row matching
          protectedRange[i].remove(); //remove protection
        }
      }

      let protection = sheet.getRange(lock_range).protect() //set protection
        .setDescription(lock_description)  //add description
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors()); //remove editors
      protection.addEditor(userEmail);
      if (protection.canDomainEdit())
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }


  else if (col == 9 && row >= 4 && value == null || value == "✅ good" || value == "❌ not good") { //check if the edited cell is empty
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); //get all protection with type range
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++) { //loop 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == lock_description) { //row matching
        protectedRange[i].remove(); //remove protection
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

- This will let you copy paste, if the users can't select from the dropdown
  menu.

**RESULT:**
[image]

Comment: I hope this helps your concern.

Comment: Thanks for code, but copying works for one cell and if I delete lock value, locked cell must be unprotected as show in my code. Is it possible work for more cells?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? on the other hand, I changed your `null` to `''`, in this line of code :`else if (col == 9 && row >= 4 && value == '' || value == "✅ good" || value == "❌ not good") { //check if the edited cell is empty` , once you delete the lock value, it unlocks the range.

Comment: Great, thanks bro, it worked. Only little problem with copying "lock" cell to several cells, it's not working. Only for one cell works

Comment: If you would like to work with multiple cells , I suggest you can do the approach of @TheMaster.